# Javascript vs AJAX for running complicated function

Tags: javascript, ajax

TLDR; I have a very complicated function that modifies form elements based on dropdown choices. Should I write the function in javascript or use AJAX to make the server run the function?

Long version:

I'm customizing a shopping cart which has dropdowns for product attributes (like Size and Color). Depending on the product, there could be anywhere from 1 to 100+ variations of the product with individually set prices and stocks.

If the customer chooses an attribute, the function checks to see if there are any out of stock options and disables them in the dropdowns. It also checks if all attributes have a selection and displays the specific price for that selection.

There's more to that function that I won't go into because it isn't exactly relevant.

Mostly, the function is a ton of `for` loops, comparing possibilities to the current selections. It also uses jQuery to disable the dropdown options and change the price HTML (in a pretty format with 2 decimals and a currency symbol).

I suppose I could try out both scenarios and compare the load time, but I don't have the resources to test it on multiple devices and with different internet speeds and it would take me a while to code it.

Is there a "general rule" for this kind of thing?

BTW, my website runs on Python.

Comment: With only 100 elements it's going to be an instant computation on the client-side, no reason to send it to the server.

Comment: Sounds like you should use both. Clientside javascript to fetch and update the dropdowns, and then serverside code to do all the comparison and checking if the product is in stock, assuming that info is stored in a database etc.

Comment: "the function checks to see if there are any out of stock options and disables them in the dropdowns"--- That kind of thing is generally better as a server side check.  Inventories change over time.